# How can I exclude Booked Slots using hasMany relationship in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
Event
---------------------

ID   Name
1    Dancing Class


EventSlots
---------------------
ID  Date
1   2021-10-26
2   2021-11-27

Orders
ID  EventID     EventSlotID
1   1           2
```

EventClass

```
class Event{

    public function slots()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(EventSlots::class, 'event_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

I've this piece of code where I query to get all the Events:

```
$events = Event::get();
```

and in my API Resource i'm returning `$event->slots` for each of the events.

When I call `$event->slots` I'm getting all the event slots related to that event but what how do I exclude the EventSlots which are already booked?

Comment: How you are identifying booked slots, means are you managing status?

Comment: if there's a related slot in eventSlots table then it is booked.